# C# parameter on cs file can't be detected on aspx

Tags: c#, .net, variables, parameters, sessionid

So I have a condition on the aspx file:

```
<% if (yes)  
   {%>
   {
<div>
    <h1>hell yes!!</h1>
    <p>Welcome</p>
</div>
<%}%>/
```

and here is my code on the page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (accnt != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
            conn.Open();
            string strSql = "select statement"
                      :
                      :
            try
            {
                if (intExists > 0)
                {
                    bool yes= check(accnt);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I get the error:

```
CS0103: The name 'yes' does not exist in the current context
```

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion, put this

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    public string yes = "";
```

Then put

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (accnt != null)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
         {
            conn.Open();
            string strSql = "select statement"
                      :
                      :
            try
            {
                if (intExists > 0)
                {
                    bool yes= check(accnt);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

`yes` is a local variable; it doesn't exist outside of the `Page_Load` method.
You need to create a `public` (or `protected`) property in the code-behind.

Comment: so does that mean i can't use that variable to check the status unless i make it global?

Comment: @gdubs: Not global, instance-level.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `yes` a protected class-level variable it will work.  The ASPX page is a separate class that inherits from the class defined in the code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `yes` within an if block - that's the scope of the variable.  Once code execution exits the if block, your `yes` variable will be queued up for garbage collection and you won't be able to access it.

One way to resolve this is declare a public property `Yes` at the page's class level, which you can set within the `Page_Load` method.  Then you should be able to access it within the .aspx.  Example:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page {
  public bool Yes()  { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`yes` is local to `Page_Load`
Either promote yes to a field or better yet, make it a public property of your class with a private setter:

```
public bool Yes { get; private set; }
```